# Accessing private properties in derived class

Tags: javascript

I am having a parent class with a private property with a setter function. In my derived class I want to override the setter function and additionally I want access a private variable from within the derived class:

```
class Mother
{
  #name
  constructor()
  {
    this.name = "Paula";
  }
  set name(aName)
  {
    this.#name = aName;
  }
  get name()
  {
    return this.#name;
  }
}

class Child extends Mother
{
  #tattooText
  constructor()
  {
    super();
    this.#tattooText = null;
  }
  set tattooText(value)
  {
    this.#tattooText = value;
  }
  get tattooText()
  {
    return this.#tattooText;
  }
  set name(aName)
  {
    super.name = aName;
    if (this.#tattooText === null)
        this.#tattooText = aName;  
  }
  get name()
  {
    return super.name;
  }
}
```

Unfortunatelly, this will not work, because I dont have access to the private #tattooText property from within the derived class. Seems like the overwritten "set name" function is getting executed in the scope of the parent class.

Do you have any idea how to solve this task? How can i get access to private properties of a derived class from within an overwritten setter function?

Regards
Robert

Edited: The problem only appears, when I try to "prefill" the name property from within a constructor in the Mother-Class. (see edited source)

Comment: If you call `super();` on the first line of the `Child` constructor, your code should work fine.

Comment: @Pointy: Unfortunatelly, it doesnt. When I create a new Child and try to set a new .name, I'll get an error

Comment: Seems to work fine https://jsfiddle.net/qpjcoh8k/ - what error do you get?

Comment: @RobertWismet what error?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] clearly demonstrating the problem and error

Comment: Well if you're overriding the setter in the child class, you should also override the getter (for `.name`). It can return `super.name` (and probably should).

Comment: Sorry, the problem only appears, when I try to "prefill" the name property from within a constructor in the mother class: https://jsfiddle.net/yoLhexdq/

Comment: you could work around the issue and change the tattooText getter to return the name if #tattooText is null?

Comment: @SteveHarris: Unfortunatelly in the real code I am doing more than just in the example ;-)

Comment: looks like you've found yourself a bug (IMO) in javascript. Although setting tattooText = null directly after calling super() would undo the Mother class setting it. Maybe just set #name in Mother and set #tattooText in the Child constructor.